# Filter a list by an integerlist using piglatin

Tags: filter, apache-pig

I have a list that looks like this: lista.csv:

```
client-id    priority    client-start    assignment
12345        1            1250125125     13
1246         3            1250122156     27
12616        1            1250122351     3
...
```

and I have another list, looking like a vector listb.csv:

```
125125
124214
1246
125
...
```

What I want do is to Filter list for all clients, whose ID I can find in listb as well.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
raw = LOAD 'lista.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (client-id: int, priority: 
int, client-start: int, assignment: int); 
s4q = LOAD 'listb.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (survs4id: int);
s4id = FOREACH s4q {
dd = FILTER raw by (client-id == s4q);
GENERATE dd;
}
DUMP dd;
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

JOIN those two relations to get only the records that match.This will act as a filter.

```
raw = LOAD 'lista.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (client-id: int, priority: int, client-start: int, assignment: int); 
s4q = LOAD 'listb.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (survs4id: int);
s4id = JOIN raw BY client-id,s4q BY survs4id;
dd = FOREACH s4id GENERATE s4id.$0,s4id.$1,s4id.$2,s4id.$3;
DUMP dd;
```